# Why does the number of ways that $n$ can be summed with at least one $1$ equal the partition function for $n-1$?

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

For some reason I was counting the number of partitions of $n$ that have at least one $1$ as an addend.  The beginning sequence for these numbers, starting with $n=1$, is $\{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 15, 22,\dots\}$. This is as far as I went, but so far this is exactly the sequence for the partitions-counting function.  I'm curious as to whether or not this sequence continues as such and, if so, why does my function, $p_1(n)$ equal the partition function, $p(n-1)$?

Comment: If you have a partition n = 1 + $a_1$ + $a_2$ + ... + $a_k$ then n-1 = $a_1$ + $a_2$ + ... + $a_k$  and conversely.

Comment: Are you going to the IMC 2015?